# Alternative for multiple inheritance in Java during GUI development

Tags: java, gwt

I ran at the following dilemma: there's no multiple inheritance in Java but I need it, how to avoid it?

Below is the reason why I started thinking about it.

I was in need of a text box that has several specific properties and behavior (on focus and on blur events are handled). I developed DecoratedTextBox without hesitation:

```
public class DecoratedTextBox extends TextBox implements FocusHandler, BlurHandler {
    public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {
        //cool feature implementation
    }

    public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
        //another cool feature
    }

    //other cool features
}
```

My GUI started looking good, but I didn't take into account PasswordTextBox. It also must have the same properties and behaviour that DecoratedTextBox has. But PasswordTextBox is inhereted from TextBox and it is in fact another class hierarchy branch. At once I remembered that it would be great if TextArea also has all those cool properties and behavior etc.

So what is wrong with my design that it leads to thoughts about multiple-inheritance? What must be done to satisfy mentioned requirements?

**Some clarification**

As a result I had to inherit from PasswordTextBox, TextArea and so on to take advantage of their features (these classes are from GWT library). But I cannot understand how to weave composition here.

**Update**

Correct me If I understood what Anders Johansen said in a wrong way.

The solution should look like this:

```
public class DecoratedTextBox extend AbstractEventHandler {
    private TextBox textBox;

    //wrap TextBox methods
    public String getText() {
        return textBox.getText();
    }
}

public class DecoratedPasswordTextBox  extend AbstractEventHandler {
    private PasswordTextBox passwordTextBox;

    //wrap TextBox methods
    //...
}

public class DecoratedTextArea  extend AbstractEventHandler {
    private TextAre textArea;

    //wrap TextBox methods
    //...
}

public abstract class AbstractEventHandler implements FocusHandler, BlurHandler {
    public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {
        //default cool feature implementation
    }

    public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
        //another default cool feature implementation
    }
}
```

**updated**

I tried variants suggested by Anders Johansen and Hilbrand Bouwkamp, but in each case I ran at a problem that I have a method (its signature cannot be changed) that adds widgets and one of the args is Widget itself. So if I'm not subclassing from something that is a subclass of Widget, I break a lot of classes.

Still continue thinking on solution.

Comment: Just for the correctness: There _is_ multiple inheritance in Java, just not for classes (implementations). For interfaces multiple inheritance exists as [stated in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html). As others have stated in their answers: Inheritance is rarely a good solution, composition is nearly always the better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't guesss what kind of cool features you like to add, but what about making a TextBoxBaseDecorator class, which looks something like:

```
public class TextBoxBaseDecorater implements FocusHandler, BlurHandler, HasAttachHandlers {
  private final TextBoxBase textBoxBase;
  private final ArrayList<HandlerRegistration> handlers = new ArrayList<HandlerRegistration>();

  /*
   * Pass the TextBoxBase extending widget to be decorated.
   */
  public TextBoxBaseDecorater(TextBoxBase textBoxBase) {
    this.textBoxBase = textBoxBase;
    textBoxBase.addAttachHandler(this);
  }

  public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {
    //cool feature implementation
  }

  public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
    //another cool feature
  }

  public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
     if (event.isAttached() {
       handlers.add(textBoxBase.addBlurHandler(this));
       handlers.add(textBoxBase.addFocusHandler(this));
     } else {
       for (HandlerRegistration rh: handlers) {
          rh.removeHandler();
       }
       handlers.clear();
     }
  }

  //other cool features
```

}

You could create subclasses that create wrappers for the specific widgets, like TextBox, PasswordTextBox and TextArea.

Comment: I'm playing now with what you suggested. But I haven't managed yet to embed new class (TextBoxDecorator) to existing code. It subclasses from TextBox, but contains TextBoxBaseDecorator field (according to composition). I override setText and getText methods in TextBoxBaseDecorator and I added wrappers to TextBoxDecorator like: getText() { return textBoxBaseDecorator.getText();} but I think I did something wrong during new classes composition.

Comment: When I call setText() it started to call setText() of callers. Let me show it on example:
TextBoxDecorator.setText(textBase.setText()) and in TextBoxBaseDecorator.setText(textBoxBase.setText()). TextBoxDecorator contains field of TextBoxBaseDecorator and the last one contains field TextBoxBase.

Answer (score 3):

You should use Interfaces for defining how things interact and base classes to enforce behavior. This way you can use composition + interfaces to explicitly get the benefits of multiple inheritance.

In your situation: Extract a common interface for the TextBox classes and use that for your DecoratedTextBox class.

Comment: +1, with the exception that `TextBox` is not the OP's own class so he can't change it: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TextBox.html

Comment: @ThomasBroyer, the same situation is with PasswordTextBox and TextArea -> they are all from GWT library.

Comment: Let's make things clearer: `DecoratedTextBox extends Composite implements <all the same interfaces as TextBox implements>`, and add `getVisibleLength` and the like that call the wrapped `TextBox`'s methods. Do the same for `DecoratedTextArea` and `DecoratedPasswordTextBox`. For that last one, you can make it `extends DecoratedTextBox` if you like. That indeed means you cannot use `DecoratedTextBox` interchangeably with `TextBox`; if you want that, then use the observer pattern (for instance, see how `TouchScroll` observes a `ScrollPanel` without the need for a `TouchScrollPanel`)

Comment: Note that, alternatively, you could use a single `DecoratedTextBox<T extends TextBoxBase> extends Composite` that you initialize with a `TextBox`, `PasswordTextBox` or `TextArea`, and you then use a `getTextBox` to deal with the wrapped box, instead of exposing the same interface. For instance, the `SuggestBox` started as a "I have the same API as `TextBox`" and has since then moved to a "I wrap a `TextBox`, if you want it, use `getTextBox()`" approach.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer, I've updated topic with example usage as I understood. Is it correct?

Comment: @Dragon, looks good to me after cursory look. If it were me I would (out of habit) do an interface for AbstractEventHandler, then a class called AbstractEventHandlerBase that looks just like AbstractEventHandler in your example. This way I future proff my code by having the interface in place to separate implementation ("class") from integration interface ("interface").

Comment: @AndersJohansen, thanks. I think the idea to extract interface from AbstractEventHandler and then create class implementing this interface is better than it is now )

Comment: @Dragon well as I said it's a matter of habit for me. I always make an interface for everything, just to be sure that I'm not tempted into getting in exactly the situation you are in. But only for production code :) The minus is that I end up with a lot of interfaces that are rarely used, and navigating the code becomes a little harder for everybody.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails you can do this:

```
public class ClassA extends TextBox implements FocusHandler {
 // ...
}

public class ClassB extends ClassA implements BlurHandler {
 // ...
}

public class DecoratedTextBox extends extends ClassB  {
    //other cool features
}
```

I'm assuming that you **want** to solve this problem with inheritance. Otherwise you can use *composition*. In most cases it will be a better alternative.

Comment: I think this is not what I need. I came to the moment when I need to inherit from PasswordTextBox (to get password feature), from TextArea (to get multiple line feature) etc.